# Parsing from a PHP page from PCL with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, php, xamarin

as beginner of Xamarin PCL i have the next question:

I build a project in VS2017. I want to scan a barcode and then send the information to a PHP website and see if the products exists.

The scanning part works great. But now i want to send the information from the PCL to the PHP website like this:

```
    string barcode_check_uri = "https://mywebsite.com/websrv/barcode_checker.php";
string _barcode = result.Text;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var uri = new Uri(barcode_check_uri);

ProductBarcode product = new ProductBarcode();

product.Barcode = _barcode;

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);

try
{
    var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response =  client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

    if (response.Content != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

    //Error here                            
    string _respnstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);


    }

}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

I got a error at the 'string _respnstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);'. I dont know how it looks like on the PHP side and on the PCL side.

Can anyone help please.  Many thanx ...

Comment: what specific error are you getting?

Comment: C# The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; Your method is not async (that's why you're calling .Result on all of your tasks. You can't use await in non-async methods.

Comment: do you understand how to use async/await?  It's fairly well documented

Comment: i found the solution. thanx